# Cropped images change in Xcode when running vs the image xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, image, crop

So I cropped a pdf file using Preview this morning and loaded them into xcode through the Images.xcassets import. They show up as the correct cropped images in the xcassets folder but when I run the project (I am loading a few into image views just to test) the cropped images seem to be shifted(down and to the left).  to areas of the original pdf image which is no where on the image in the xcassets picture.

So I think that part of the issue is that they were saved as PDF files rather than an image type so I exported one as a jpeg, put it in xcassets and it is showing the correct image.

Comment: "… it is showing the correct issue." Does that mean the jpeg *does* work, or that it *doesn't* work?

Comment: Image*, it is working now, sorry for the typo.